# How to check MongoDB connection usning unittest and Python

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test in Python to check MongoDB connection, and at the end check if there is duplicated fields. 
Does anyone know how to write a Python unittest for checking server or local host connection with MongoDB?

Thanks in advance.